# Ошибка при подключении к базе Postgress

Tags: c#, postgresql

В моем проекте мне нужно использовать Postgres базу, до этого момента небыло опыта работы с такой базой, настроил субд на компе все работает. Пробую из приложения подключиться к базе возникает ошибка. Причем все пакеты установлены.
Делаю так.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Npgsql;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=test;";
            var npgSqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            npgSqlConnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Соединение с БД открыто");

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка,

```
System.ArgumentException: "Keyword not supported: user
Имя параметра: keyword"
```

Подскажите почему так, вроде прочитал что пишут про это но не помогает. В GAG все добавлено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формат строки подключения к Postgres предполагает параметр "User Id=", а не "User=".

```
String connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=test;"
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало.